# Getting id_path or request_path or target_path of current category or product page

Tags: redirect

I have many store views. I need to be able to retrieve id_path or request_path or target_path of current category or product page, so that I could retrieve target_path of the same category or product page for a different store view.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for the hreflang tags.

To make things easier I have the same url-key for the products, set to the product name and colour. Fortunately the model names are the same in all languages for this catalogue. I don't include the category path in the URL, model name and colour gives the uniques.

When it comes to categories, here is how I do it for the sitemaps. I am sure you can make this code more elegant, however, it is not something that needs to be fast for a user so I have gone for code that works rather than optimised code. My store codes are things like 'en_us' and I do a bit of manipulation on that, but here is the loop I have:

```
    /**
     * Generate categories sitemap
     */
    $changefreq = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/changefreq', $storeId);
    $priority   = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/priority', $storeId);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_category')->getCollection($storeId);
    $categories = new Varien_Object();
    $categories->setItems($collection);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_categories_generating_before', array(
        'collection' => $categories
    ));
    foreach ($categories->getItems() as $item) {
        $hreflangs ='';
        foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
            foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
                $stores = $group->getStores();
                foreach ($stores as $store) {
                    $code = explode('_', $store->getCode());
                    $hreflang = $code[0];
                    if(isset($code[1])) $hreflang .= '-' . strtolower($code[1]);
                    $rewriteUrl = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId($store->getId())->loadByIdPath('category/'. $item->getId());
                    if ($rewriteUrl->getId()) {
                        $link = $rewriteUrl->getRequestPath();
                    } else {
                        $link = $item->getUrl();
                    }
                    $hreflangs .= '<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK) . $link . '" hreflang="' . $hreflang . '"/>' . "\n";
                }
            }
        }

        $xml = sprintf(
            '<url><loc>%s</loc>%s<lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
            htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()),
            $hreflangs,
            substr(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($item->getId())->getUpdatedAt(),0,10),
            $changefreq,
            $priority
        );
        $io->streamWrite($xml);
    }
    unset($collection);
```

This results in things like:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://local.example.com/en_gb/men/key-holders</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/it_it/men/portachiavi" hreflang="it-it"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/en_eu/men/key-holders" hreflang="en-eu"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/it_gb/men/portachiavi" hreflang="it-gb"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/en_gb/men/key-holders" hreflang="en-gb"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/it_us/men/portachiavi" hreflang="it-us"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/en_us/men/key-holders" hreflang="en-us"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/it/men/portachiavi" hreflang="it"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://local.example.com/en/men/key-holders" hreflang="en"/>
    <lastmod>2015-01-09</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

It is still early days for me on this, please let me know if I am getting my hreflang tags wrong!

Needless to say the same technique should work for products.